# How to use a custom post type slug within another custom post type's slug

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I have created two custom post types in my wordpress project: **city** and **property** using the below query.

```
register_post_type('city',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __('City', 'dc_qode'),
                    'singular_name' => __('City', 'dc_qode'),
                ),
                'public'    =>  true,
                'show_in_menu'  =>  true,
                'rewrite'     =>  array('slug' => 'city'),
                'show_ui'   =>  true,
                'has_archive' =>  false,
                'hierarchical'  =>  true,
                'show_tagcloud' => false,
                'supports' => array(
                    'title',
                    'editor',
                    'thumbnail',
                ),
                'can_export' => true,
                'taxonomies' => array( 'city'),
            )
        );


register_post_type('property',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __('Property', 'dc_qode'),
                    'singular_name' => __('Property', 'dc_qode'),
                ),
                'public'    =>  true,
                'show_in_menu'  =>  true,
                'rewrite'     =>  array('slug' => 'property'),
                'show_ui'   =>  true,
                'has_archive' =>  false,
                'hierarchical'  =>  true,
                'show_tagcloud' => false,
                'supports' => array(
                    'title',
                    'editor',
                    'thumbnail',
                ),
                'can_export' => true,
                'taxonomies' => array( 'property'),
            )
        );
```

Using this, I can access any property using the url `http://domain-name.com/property/property-name`. But I want to access the url as `http://domain-name.com/city-name/property-name` (for eg. `http://domain-name.com/toronto/abcproperty`). The city-name will be assigned with each property. I tried to use the slug, 'city', within property as:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => '%city%')
```

in place of

```
'rewrite'     =>  array('slug' => 'property')
```

But it's not working.

How can I achieve this scenario?

Comment: @all: Isn't there any solution for this?

Comment: you could turn City into a taxonomy, and then you would be able to achieve it that way -

Comment: Then when you access the archive of city taxonomy, you would get an archive of the cities in "toronto" automatically.

Comment: @Stender: Can you please suggest how to turn City into a taxonomy? I didn't understand your suggestion properly.

Comment: Instead of having 2 post types, cities could be a taxonomy for property.

Comment: basically, you run `register_taxonomy` instead of `register_post_type` but you need to change some stuff. Read about it here : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/

Comment: Can you please share the code as per your suggestion?

Comment: @Debashis Are you looking for a parent child relationship for your CPT ?

Comment: @AnoopD: No, Just want to hide the post type name from the url and add the city name with the property. The city name will be selected using dropdown while adding the property information.

Comment: @Debashis The city name will be selected using dropdown while adding the property information ? And saved as post_meta ?

Comment: @AnoopD: I have 2 custom post types: city and property. We can add the city names like Toronto, Bampton etc. under the City. And while adding the property information using the property post type, admin will be able to select the specific city names (that we already created using city post_type) using dropdown option. So, yes, the while adding the property information, city name/post_id of that city will be saved as post_meta for that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your custom posts to have parents like page. So there are three main thing you have to do:

1. Make you custom post to support Page attributes.
2. You have to register new rewrite rule, which will then define a new permastruct which will be used in the third step.
3. After registering the new rewrite rule, you should apply this rule to your custom posts' permalinks.

   Complete working code

   ```
   add_action('init', function(){
       $labels = array(
           "name" => "City",
           "singular_name" => "City",
           "menu_name" => "City",
           "all_items" => "All City",
           "add_new" => "Add New",
           "add_new_item" => "Add New City",
           "edit" => "Edit",
           "edit_item" => "Edit City",
           "new_item" => "New City",
           "view" => "View",
           "view_item" => "View City",
           "search_items" => "Search City",
           "not_found" => "No City Found",
           "not_found_in_trash" => "No City Found in Trash",
           "parent" => "Parent City",
       );

       $args = array(
           "labels" => $labels,
            "description" => "",
           "public" => true,
           "show_ui" => true,
           "has_archive" => true,
           "show_in_menu" => true,
           "exclude_from_search" => false,
           "capability_type" => "post",
           "map_meta_cap" => true,
           "hierarchical" => true,
           "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "city", "with_front" => true ),
           "query_var" => true,
           "supports" => array( "title", "revisions", "thumbnail" )
       );

       register_post_type( "city", $args );

       $labels = array(
           "name" => "Properties",
           "singular_name" => "Property",
       );

       $args = array(
           "labels" => $labels,
           "description" => "",
           "public" => true,
           "show_ui" => true,
           "has_archive" => true,
           "show_in_menu" => true,
           "exclude_from_search" => false,
           "capability_type" => "post",
           "map_meta_cap" => true,
           "hierarchical" => false,
           "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "city/%city_name%", "with_front" => true ),
           "query_var" => true,
           "supports" => array( "title", "revisions", "thumbnail" )
       );

       register_post_type( "properties", $args );

   });

   add_action('add_meta_boxes', function() {
       add_meta_box('properties-parent', 'City', 'properties_attributes_meta_box', 'properties', 'side', 'default');
   });

   function properties_attributes_meta_box($post) {
           $pages = wp_dropdown_pages(array('post_type' => 'city', 'selected' => $post->post_parent, 'name' => 'parent_id', 'show_option_none' => __('(no parent)'), 'sort_column'=> 'menu_order, post_title', 'echo' => 0));
           if ( ! empty($pages) ) {
               echo $pages;
           } // end empty pages check
   }

   add_action( 'init', function() {

       add_rewrite_rule( '^city/(.*)/([^/]+)/?$','index.php?properties=$matches[2]','top' );

   });

   add_filter( 'post_type_link', function( $link, $post ) {
       if ( 'properties' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
           //Lets go to get the parent city name
           if( $post->post_parent ) {
               $parent = get_post( $post->post_parent );
               if( !empty($parent->post_name) ) {
                   return str_replace( '%city_name%', $parent->post_name, $link );
               }
           } else {
               //This seems to not work. It is intented to build pretty permalinks
               //when properties has not parent, but it seems that it would need
               //additional rewrite rules
               //return str_replace( '/%city_name%', '', $link );
           }

       }
       return $link;
   }, 10, 2 );
   ```

Comment: I have followed your suggestion and implemented it. And findings are: 1) The default url is showing as http://domain-name.com/property/property-name within wp-admin  and the property can be viwed using this url in frontend.  2) If I use the url like http://domain-name.com/toronto/property-name then the url is redirecting to  http://domain-name.com/property/property-name. So, my purpose is not solved.

Comment: As mentioned, maybe the previous code is missing something, so i had to write it from scratch. please test it

Comment: This works but there is another issue on it. I have few other custom post types in my project like neighborhood, builders etc. When I am trying to view any specific page of those custom post type (http://domain-name.com/builder/abc  or http://domain-name.com/neighborhood/xyz), they are giving 404 - Page not found.

Comment: I had to modify it to match some conditions are my criteria to work it. But, the main idea behind that is your above suggestion. Thank you.